# I am stuck in Servlet and HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, backend

I am working on a project to develop an online food ordering website.
I am using HTML, CSS and JavaScript for frontend and Java (Servlets) for backend and PostgreSQL as my database. I am also using Apache Tomcat server for deploying the website on localhost.

I have created a login page for admin (photos available below) and I have a servlet called as AdminPage which checks for username and password in database and if it matches correctly it logs user in (Displays Admin Page to Admin).

My problem is that when the login fails (user enters wrong username or password) the Login page should itself display the error (sort of like how forum.freecodecamp.org does when we enter wrong credentials) but I don’t know how to do it.

Currently what I do is I use RequestDispatcher to forward the request to another page if login fails (photos available below) and that page has a “Try Again” button which takes user back to login page.
But I don’t want this I want the current page (Login Page) to itself display the error message to user that their username or password is invalid.

Login page photo:

[image]

Login failed page photo:

[image]

Login page HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Card</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./LoginCard.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="AdminPage" method="post">
            <h3>Admin Login</h3>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            <button>Login</button>
            <p class="login-failed">Invalid Username or password, please try again.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login Page CSS Code :

```
*,
*:before ,
*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 430px;
    height: 520px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

form {
    height: 520px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6);
    padding: 50px 35px;
}

body {
    background: url(./res-img-small\ cropped.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

form *{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

form h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

input {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

::placeholder {
    color: #080710;
}

button {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #080710;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.login-failed {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

AdminPage.java code ( Servlet which I use to verify username and password from database )

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;



public class AdminPage extends HttpServlet {

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, 
        ServletException
        {
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
                    res.setContentType("text/html");
                    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                    String user, pass;
                    user = req.getParameter("username");
                    pass = req.getParameter("password");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Online_Food_Ordering_System",
                            "postgres", "password");
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_login WHERE username = ? and password = ? ";
                    PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    myStmt.setString(1,user);
                    myStmt.setString(2,pass);
                    ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<h1>Login Successfull</h1>");
                        out.println("</body>");
                        out.println("</html>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("LoginFailed.html");  
                        rd.forward(req, res);  
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
        }
}
```

When the login fails I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Also a slight animation of the error message (moving a little left and right for few seconds so as to capture attention would be quite nice [ I don’t know how to implement it though ]).

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what you want to achieve is being done in this example [RequestDispatcher forward and include Login example](https://youtu.be/H2pwtINs5ck) by using the RequestDispatcher.include method

Comment: Thank You for replying , yes requestdispatcher include method includes the text in current html file but it remains unformatted ( the text gets inserted as if there are no other elements on the page i.e. it appears on the top left column only ) I tried adding class to the text but nothing happened. Isn't there any other way like something which will check if user is logged in and if user is successfully logged in it will set display property of preapplied class to block.( which would be initially none.)